# Self-hosted point-and-click tool to create scrolling web data stories

Tags: web-apps, web-development, data-visualization, self-hosted

I am looking for a tool to create web data stories.

**The result** should be a web page where a story evolves when you scroll down the page with some moving animations. It could look like this:

- https://www.abc.net.au/news/2022-06-29/census-australia-as-100-people/101181614
- https://www.abc.net.au/news/2023-07-17/fifa-2023-womens-world-cup-best-player-data/102529722

or this (in German):

- https://scrlly.com/stories/die-entdeckung-des-sensiblen-ich

**The tool** should have a point-and-click interface so that non-programmers can put a story together which than is "published" top be read by a wider audience.

**The server** where story result and point-and-click interface are hosted should be on-premises/self-hosted, so that creation tool and final story are held in-house.

Open-source or proprietary, paid software, both would be fine.